# apache2 rewrite subfolder and file extension

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want to rewrite `domain.com/pages/welcome.php`
to `domain.com/welcome` using `htaccess` under apach2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .htaccess in the document root ,add this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pages/welcome/?$ /pages/welcome.php [L]
```

This will allow you to access **welcome.php** file without its extension.